# problem with binarysearch algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-search

the code below belongs to binary search algorithm,user enter numbers in textbox1 and enter the number that he want to fing with binarysearch in textbox2.i have  a problem with it,that is when i enter for example 15,21 in textbox1 and enter 15 in textbox2 and put brakpoint on the line i commented below,and i understood that it doesnt put the number in textbox2 in searchnums(commented),for more explanation i comment in code.thanks in advance

```
 public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        int searchnums = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);//the problem is here,the value in textbox2 doesnt exist in searchnums and it has value 0. 

        int result = binarysearch(searchnums);
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
    }
    public int binarysearch(int searchnum)
    {
        string[] source = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
        int[] nums = new int[source.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            nums[i] = Convert.ToInt32(source[i]);
        }

        int first =0;

        int last = nums.Length-1;


        while (1<= nums.Length)
        {
        int mid = (int)Math.Floor(first+last / 2.0);
             if (first > last)
            {
                break;
            }
            if (searchnum < nums[mid])
            {
                last = mid - 1;
            }
            if (searchnum > nums[mid])
            {
                first = mid + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return nums[mid];

            }
        }
        return -1; 


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you know you can place a breakpoint on a line, you sure know you can step through the **whole** program and see what values are in each variable or property. So, go ahead, and debug. Among other things you are probably missing data input validation in your program.

Second, your binary search implementation is missing `mid` recalculation after `first` or `last` is updated and a stop condition in case the number being looked for is not found in the array. You have to break the loop in case `first == last`, regardless if `nums[mid]` matches or not — nobody said the number from `textbox2` *must* be in the array.

Comment: the problem  very simple,i didnt pressed f10 for step over the program,thanks

Answer (score 2):

What does it have to do with binary search? The problem seems to be that you can't read the number out of a textbox. Are you sure it's the right textbox? What is it's Text? Also, if you put the breakpoint ON the line that assigns the value to searchnums, it will be 0, because it hasn't been assigned yet, put the breakpoint on the line AFTER.

Comment: the user enter some numbers in textbox1 and it should find the specific number that use enter in textbox2 with this algorithm if it exist.yes the textbox is right

Comment: so what is textBox2.Text? is the problem that the value doesn't get parsed into searchnums and it's zero?

Comment: i said that in textbox2 user enter the specific number that he want to find

Comment: if you can't answer a simple question, then I can't help you. please tell us what you see in the debugger when you put a breakpoint after the convert.toint32 line.

Comment: what should i see?result have the value 0 and searchnums have value 0

Comment: if searchnums is 0 after reading the textbox text and converting it to int32, that means that textBox2.Text is also "0", so you didn't enter/read the value in/from the correct textbox.

Comment: i saw the value exist in textBox2.text,the problem is the value doesn't get parsed into searchnums and it's zero

Comment: Try to enter 25 in textBox2. Then enter these in the debugger watch: int.Parse("25"), int.Parse(textBox2.text), "25" == textBox2.Text

Answer (score 1):

OK, first of all, I hope you know that binary search won't work if `nums` isn't sorted.

That said, there are a few problems in the algorithm. First of all, you're not changing any of the key elements in the loop. You're only changing `first` and `last` in the loop and they aren't even used there, so the loop's state doesn't change.

So i guess you meant to have this line in the beginning of the loop:

```
mid = (first +last)/2;
```

Besides that, you need to check for the very likely event that the number doesn't exist. which means adding this in the beginning of the loop to:

```
if (last < first) break;
```

Which of course means that the first point of the array block has passed the last point, which means the block size is negative. `first == last` may be legal when you get to the last cell in the array.

And the last point is to initiate `last` as size-1:

```
int last = nums.Length - 1;
```

We're talking about array indexes after all.

Comment: thanks,why when first<last it should break?first can be less than last

Comment: We're talking about indexes, not actual values, there's no point in having the last position before the first.

Comment: i edited my question according to your points,but it has the problem yet,you can see my edit,thanks

Comment: You still aren't changing the value of mid. Which means the loop's state won't change , you're still only comparing 2 numbers in the whole loop: searchnum , nums[mid] ... Because mid is always the same.