# problem with converting numbers in textBox

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-search

The code below belongs to a binary search algorithm. The user enters numbers in `textbox1` and enters the number that he want to find with binarysearch in `textbox2`. When I enter for example 16 in `textBox2` and put breakpoint on the line I commented, I see that the value of searchnum is 10.

I think it converts to hexadecimal. I don't know why. Can you help me?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] source = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
    int[] nums = new int[source.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        nums[i] = Convert.ToInt32(source[i]);
    }

    string str_searchnum = textBox2.Text;
    int searchnum = Convert.ToInt32(str_searchnum); // str_searchnum shows the value 16 but searchnum shows 10
    int first = 0;

    int last = nums.Length - 1;

    while (1 < nums.Length - 1)
    {
        int mid = (int)Math.Floor(first + last / 2.0);

        ////if (first < last)
        ////{
        ////    break;
        ////}

        if (searchnum < nums[mid])
        {
            last = mid - 1;
        }
        if (searchnum > nums[mid])
        {
            first = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(nums[mid].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem with binarysearch algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529884/problem-with-binarysearch-algorithm)

Comment: the problem of that question was i didnt use step over for debugging but now i used that and have this problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to see if the debugger is set to display values using hexadecimal notation? You can find this option by right clicking in the watch window.

If that's not it, step through the entire method. What is the value of str_searchnum?

Although I personally prefer int.TryParse(), Convert.ToInt32() should be well-tested and not be doing any base conversions.

Comment: i didnt find where is the option,can you explain me more?
the value of str_searchnum is 16 and its correct

Comment: What did you try? Did you right click in the watch window? Is there a command in that menu that says Hexadecimal or something like that?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/10/14/the-watch-window-hexadecimal-display-vstiptool0110.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Array.BinarySearch? Also, your loop condition is (probably) wrong.